# Itext pdf issue with pdf file rotation

Tags: pdf, rotation, itext

I'm using ItextPdf PdfSmartCopy and PdfDictionary. I've to detect the rotation of the input pdf file, based on rotation I've to decide how much should I rotate in order to bring it to zero degree(Normal view). Generally if the user scan the file, rotates it either left or right before saving, my program has to detect it when user uploads. I'm using the below code but for all the different types of files, rotation comes as zero only. Any idea how I can fix it?

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader existing = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader("c:\\pdf_issue\\rotate270.pdf");
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document1 = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document1, new FileOutputStream("c:\\pdf_issue\\TestRotation270.pdf"));
        document1.open();
    int n1 = existing.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfDictionary pageDict;
        int rot;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n1; i++) {
            rot = existing.getPageRotation(i);

            switch(rot)
            {
            case 90:
               {
                pageDict = existing.getPageN(i);
                pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 270));
                 break;
               }
            case 180:
               {
                pageDict = existing.getPageN(i);
                pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 180));
                 break;            
}
            case 270:
               {
                pageDict = existing.getPageN(i);
                pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 90));
               break;
}
            default:
               {
                pageDict = existing.getPageN(i);
                pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rot + 0));
               break;
}
            }

        }
        for (int page = 0; page < n1; ) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(existing, ++page));
        }
    document1.close();
```

But if I explicitly rotate a file without detecting the rotation, file gets rotated by whatever standard degree I give.

Comment: Show us the PDF. If all pages have rotation zero, than all pages have rotation zero. Maybe you are assuming that a page in landscape always has rotation 90. That assumption would be wrong.

Comment: Probably inherited rotation? If you share the PDF, we can check.